# Emails sent from local wp webserver are beeing rejected from Siren?

Tags: email

This is the error email I receive after wp is sending an email:

> This is the mail system at host mees-MacBook-Pro.local.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```
>
> : host mxcluster1.one.com[91.198.169.8] said: 450
>   4.7.1    Recipient address rejected: xx.xxx.xx.xxx temporary greylisted by CYREN IP    reputation (in reply to RCPT TO command)
>   Reporting-MTA: dns; mees-MacBook-Pro.local X-Postfix-Queue-ID:
>   18F8945ABC66 X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; mee@mydomain.no Arrival-Date:
>   Sat,  1 Jul 2017 15:21:00 +0200 (CEST)
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; mee@mydomain.no Action: failed Status: 4.7.1
>   Remote-MTA: dns; mxcluster1.one.com Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 450 4.7.1
>   Recipient address rejected: xx.xxx.xx.xxx    temporary greylisted by
>   CYREN IP reputation
>
> Fra: customer Terrassehus  Emne: [Sameiet customer
>   Terrassehus] Ny kundeordre (3496) - 1. juli 2017 Dato: 1. juli 2017
>   kl. 15.21.00 CEST Til: mee@mydomain.no

Can anybody shed some light on this. I have been greylisted by Cyren, how?  What has happened? How can I avoid this. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a mail server running on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. wordpress running from a local machine.

Comment: A lot of mail servers will reject mail sent by localhost servers. This is an anti-spam protection. In order to get around this, you need a Fully Qualified Domain Name. If you can set it up to use a GMail account or something, then you can use that for testing.

Comment: Okay, so I guess a Fully Qualified Domain Name will be overkill since its only me receiving test emails. So the solution you suggest is to use a gmail email address as the email wp is sending emails from? If that is the case, I have to tell you that I have previously also been graylisted from Cyren when  using a gmail email. But since you are suggesting this as a solution, maybe I need to configure my gmail email in some manner?

Comment: I just used them as an example. You could use any provider like GMail, Outlook, etc. You might also contact Cyren and see what's up.